# Problem uploading double precision values from csv via Liquibase to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, precision, liquibase

I try to use a csv file to upload my seed data to my database via Liquibase.
Its working for most of my files, but one contains double values and I get the message:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:   
ERROR: column "cost" is of type double precision but expression is of type character varying  
Hinweis: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

The csv looks something like this:

```
id;cost;cost_total_amount_due;external_usage_id;date
1;2.64;1400.12;4690628034847879278;2021-01-01T00:00:00
2;2.89;1389.48;4710591818684646637;2021-01-01T00:00:00
3;3.07;1326.49;4702017385332378912;2021-01-01T00:00:00
4;2.9;1542.05;4705617753718220084;2021-01-01T00:00:00
5;3.19;1450.21;4708875018849887666;2021-01-01T00:00:00
```

And the changelog like this:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: usagesCsvData
      author: malte_enbergs
      changes:
        - loadData:
            tableName: usages
            separator: ;
            file: classpath:/liquibase/data/usages.csv
```

I already tried to explicitly specify the column to NUMERIC:

```
columns:
   - column:
        header: cost
        type: NUMERIC
```

Probably it is a pretty rookie mistake, that i have to write the values different or something, but I have a hard time finding solutions.

So thank you for your help, if I should provide anything else just let me know.
Kind reguards
Malte

Comment: Are you using float in your SQL to indicate that you want to use double precision? https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-use-the-postgresql-double-precision-type-1435

Answer (score 0):

Just change `header` to `name` in your column definition.

```
columns:
  - column:
    name: cost
    type: NUMERIC
```